# What does this "$\times$" in $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I saw this $\times$ symbol several times, but couldn't find what it means.

Comment: It means the multplicative group of the invertible elements of $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Often it is written as $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$, the $U$ standing for "units".

Comment: It is not an x but a `×` (times).

Comment: Assuming it's written as a superscript, as in $(\mathbb{R}/8\mathbb{R})^{\times}$, then JWTanner's answer below is what it means.

Comment: In general, for a commutative (finite) ring $R$ (or field $F$) with the full structure $(R,+,\cdot)$ (respectively $(F,+,\cdot)$ the associated structure of the invertible elements in the ring, with the (restricted) operation of multiplication is denoted by $R^\times$ and/or $R^*$ (respectively $F^\times$ and/or $F^*$, and of course, for a field we eliminate only the zero element from $F$ to get the set $F^\times$). This is rather using the "same sign" as in the notation notation $\Bbb R^*$  (for the set of real numbers without zero) in similar more general situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.

$(\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)^\times$ means the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) of units (invertible elements) modulo $8$.

It's $\{1,3,5,7\}$ with multiplication mod $8$ as a group.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times$ is also the set of integers  $n$ such that

$$1\le n <8 \text{ and } \gcd(8,n)=1.$$

It contains $\phi(8) $ elements, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Comment: _Biointeger_ ?????????????