# How to find all group homomorphisms $\left(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right) ^\times\to \left(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\right )^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Are there other group homomorphisms $f: \left(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right) ^\times\to \left(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\right )^\times$ other than

$$f: \left(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right) ^\times\to \left(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\right )^\times, ~x \mapsto e$$

with $e$ being the identity element - and if yes, how can I find them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1$ must be mapped to $1$.

$2^2=1$ in $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times$,

so $2$ must be mapped to $1$ (which is the solution you mentioned) or $4$ in $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: [homomorphism maps identity to identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647697/tricks-prove-homomorphism-maps-identity-to-identity-fraleigh-p-128-theorem)

Comment: and solutions to $x^2\equiv1\pmod5$ are $x\equiv\pm1\pmod5$

Comment: $1$ is the identity in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ denotes the [multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)

Comment: See the comment of [Dan Fulea](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/550003/dan-fulea) on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434428/what-does-this-times-in-bbb-z-8-bbb-z-times-mean):  if $R$ is a ring (call the operations addition and multiplication), then $R^\times$ is the group of elements of the ring that have multiplicative inverses, with the multiplication operation in the ring

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If all you care about is the multiplicative structure these are cyclic groups of order $2$ and $4$. The fact that they come from fields is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, $\overline 2\in \Bbb Z_3^×$ is a generator of order $2$. So, $\overline 2\mapsto \overline 4\in \Bbb Z_5^×$ is the only possible non-trivial homomorphism.

Comment: An element $g$ of a group $G$ is said to be generator if $G=\{g^n:n\in \Bbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times\cong \mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$ for all primes $p,$ a homomorphism $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times\rightarrow (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$ is the same as a group homomorphism $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z.$ Now, $0$ has to go to $0,$ but $1$ can go to either $0$ or $2,$ (since $f(1)+f(1)=f(1+1)=f(0)=0$) so there are two such homomorphisms.

Comment: $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ but not in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$